# 2 requests on JSP second one deletes variables contents

Tags: java, jsp, orbeon

I'm getting 2 requests on a JSP page, then I process data in Util class. But how can I keep data from first request ? It seems like second request deletes all content of first request I save in vars.

Request are issued by 2 different send() in my orbeon process.

Here is how I would like to save my data on JSP :

```
// read request parameters
String documentId = request.getParameter("document");
String pdfUrl = "";
String base64Data = "";
// read request content (XML data entered by the user)
String data = Utils.readRequestBody(request);
if (Utils.isUrl(data)) {
    pdfUrl = Utils.getUrl(data);
} else {
    base64Data = Utils.encodeb64(data);
}
```

Here are my methods in Utils class :

```
    public static boolean isUrl(String data) {
        boolean isUrl = false;
        String urlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><uri>";
        if (data.toLowerCase().contains(urlString.toLowerCase())) {
            isUrl = true;
        }
        return isUrl;
    }

    public static String getUrl(String data) {
        String urlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><uri>";
        data = data.substring(urlString.length(), data.length()-7);
        return data;
    }
 public static String readRequestBody(HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // important to add lineSeparator to preserve line feeds in multiline text fields
            sb.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public static String encodeb64(String s) {
        return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(s.getBytes()));
    }
```

So I think I didn't understand something so I need help to learn how to handle this case.

Best regards,

Joseph

Comment: Usually data are stored in session (if You speak about request in the same session). Or in files, database etc..

Comment: You should also not keep Java code in a JSP. Instead separate the view (JSP) and the business logic (Servlet). It also becomes clearer what's happening when you don't have everything in the same place. Unfortunately if you're used to PHP's (awful and bug-prone) way of writing everything together in the same place, this may seem annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to create HttpSession in the JSP to make it work. Thank you @Jacek Cz for the reminder about this.